# how to take mysql backup through mysqldump command with affecting production server?

Tags: mysql, database

i have written a shell script take daily backups but whenever it starts mysql it locks the database and site goes down.

i want not to affect live server
as site can acces over different timezone so cant take back ups at night

Comment: how about using [replication](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/onlamp/2005/06/16/MySQLian.html) as backup?

Comment: [Replication is not backup](http://www.unitrends.com/blog/replication-is-not-backup-backup-is-backup/)

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can take to avoid this problem is to set up [MySQL replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) and use the slave database to do the backups from.

The pros are you get complete replication of your database and can effectively do hot backups, regardless of the type of database.
However, you do need another db server, and effectively double the storage capacity (as you are maintaining another copy of the db)

Not everyone's cup of tea, but an option nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MyISAM you can inform MySQL you don't want to lock the tables by using `--lock-tables=false`. If you're using InnoDB you can use `--single-transaction` to avoid locks.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: thanks !!! i m using mixed type table (innodb and myisam)

by the way i used 

--skip-lock-tables [option]

Answer (score 0):

solves the problem

mysqldump -u[user] -p[password] dbname --skip-lock-tables | gzip > soohoo_backup.sql.gz

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p[password] [dbname] > dumpfile.sql
```